# How to run TinyB library in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, ubuntu-16.04

I tried installing tinyb from the repository: https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb

I've build the tinyb.jar and add it to the IntellJ project as a library.

I ran the sample code provided in tinyb examples with small modification(commented out some code in the main method before the Bluetooth Manager initialization):

```
import tinyb.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class HelloTinyB {
private static final float SCALE_LSB = 0.03125f;
static boolean running = true;

static void printDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    System.out.print("Address = " + device.getAddress());
    System.out.print(" Name = " + device.getName());
    System.out.print(" Connected = " + device.getConnected());
    System.out.println();
}

static float convertCelsius(int raw) {
    return raw / 128f;
}

/*
 * After discovery is started, new devices will be detected. We can get a list of all devices through the manager's
 * getDevices method. We can the look through the list of devices to find the device with the MAC which we provided
 * as a parameter. We continue looking until we find it, or we try 15 times (1 minutes).
 */
static BluetoothDevice getDevice(String address) throws InterruptedException {
    BluetoothManager manager = BluetoothManager.getBluetoothManager();
    BluetoothDevice sensor = null;
    for (int i = 0; (i < 15) && running; ++i) {
        List<BluetoothDevice> list = manager.getDevices();
        if (list == null)
            return null;

        for (BluetoothDevice device : list) {
            printDevice(device);
            /*
             * Here we check if the address matches.
             */
            if (device.getAddress().equals(address))
                sensor = device;
        }

        if (sensor != null) {
            return sensor;
        }
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    }
    return null;
}

/*
 * Our device should expose a temperature service, which has a UUID we can find out from the data sheet. The service
 * description of the SensorTag can be found here:
 * http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/a/a8/BLE_SensorTag_GATT_Server.pdf. The service we are looking for has the
 * short UUID AA00 which we insert into the TI Base UUID: f000XXXX-0451-4000-b000-000000000000
 */
static BluetoothGattService getService(BluetoothDevice device, String UUID) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Services exposed by device:");
    BluetoothGattService tempService = null;
    List<BluetoothGattService> bluetoothServices = null;
    do {
        bluetoothServices = device.getServices();
        if (bluetoothServices == null)
            return null;

        for (BluetoothGattService service : bluetoothServices) {
            System.out.println("UUID: " + service.getUUID());
            if (service.getUUID().equals(UUID))
                tempService = service;
        }
        Thread.sleep(4000);
    } while (bluetoothServices.isEmpty() && running);
    return tempService;
}

static BluetoothGattCharacteristic getCharacteristic(BluetoothGattService service, String UUID) {
    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();
    if (characteristics == null)
        return null;

    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics) {
        if (characteristic.getUUID().equals(UUID))
            return characteristic;
    }
    return null;
}

/*
 * This program connects to a TI SensorTag 2.0 and reads the temperature characteristic exposed by the device over
 * Bluetooth Low Energy. The parameter provided to the program should be the MAC address of the device.
 *
 * A wiki describing the sensor is found here: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2650_SensorTag_User's_Guide
 *
 * The API used in this example is based on TinyB v0.3, which only supports polling, but v0.4 will introduce a
 * simplied API for discovering devices and services.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

//        if (args.length < 1) {
//            System.err.println("Run with <device_address> argument");
//            System.exit(-1);
//        }

    /*
     * To start looking of the device, we first must initialize the TinyB library. The way of interacting with the
     * library is through the BluetoothManager. There can be only one BluetoothManager at one time, and the
     * reference to it is obtained through the getBluetoothManager method.
     */
    BluetoothManager manager = BluetoothManager.getBluetoothManager();

    /*
     * The manager will try to initialize a BluetoothAdapter if any adapter is present in the system. To initialize
     * discovery we can call startDiscovery, which will put the default adapter in discovery mode.
     */
    boolean discoveryStarted = manager.startDiscovery();

    System.out.println("The discovery started: " + (discoveryStarted ? "true" : "false"));
    BluetoothDevice sensor = getDevice(args[0]);

    /*
     * After we find the device we can stop looking for other devices.
     */
    try {
        manager.stopDiscovery();
    } catch (BluetoothException e) {
        System.err.println("Discovery could not be stopped.");
    }

    if (sensor == null) {
        System.err.println("No sensor found with the provided address.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.print("Found device: ");
    printDevice(sensor);

    if (sensor.connect())
        System.out.println("Sensor with the provided address connected");
    else {
        System.out.println("Could not connect device.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    Condition cv = lock.newCondition();

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            running = false;
            lock.lock();
            try {
                cv.signalAll();
            } finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }

        }
    });


    BluetoothGattService tempService = getService(sensor, "f000aa00-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");

    if (tempService == null) {
        System.err.println("This device does not have the temperature service we are looking for.");
        sensor.disconnect();
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    System.out.println("Found service " + tempService.getUUID());

    BluetoothGattCharacteristic tempValue = getCharacteristic(tempService, "f000aa01-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic tempConfig = getCharacteristic(tempService, "f000aa02-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic tempPeriod = getCharacteristic(tempService, "f000aa03-0451-4000-b000-000000000000");

    if (tempValue == null || tempConfig == null || tempPeriod == null) {
        System.err.println("Could not find the correct characteristics.");
        sensor.disconnect();
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    System.out.println("Found the temperature characteristics");

    /*
     * Turn on the Temperature Service by writing 1 in the configuration characteristic, as mentioned in the PDF
     * mentioned above. We could also modify the update interval, by writing in the period characteristic, but the
     * default 1s is good enough for our purposes.
     */
    byte[] config = { 0x01 };
    tempConfig.writeValue(config);

    /*
     * Each second read the value characteristic and display it in a human readable format.
     */
    while (running) {
        byte[] tempRaw = tempValue.readValue();
        System.out.print("Temp raw = {");
        for (byte b : tempRaw) {
            System.out.print(String.format("%02x,", b));
        }
        System.out.print("}");

        /*
         * The temperature service returns the data in an encoded format which can be found in the wiki. Convert the
         * raw temperature format to celsius and print it. Conversion for object temperature depends on ambient
         * according to wiki, but assume result is good enough for our purposes without conversion.
         */
        int objectTempRaw = (tempRaw[0] & 0xff) | (tempRaw[1] << 8);
        int ambientTempRaw = (tempRaw[2] & 0xff) | (tempRaw[3] << 8);

        float objectTempCelsius = convertCelsius(objectTempRaw);
        float ambientTempCelsius = convertCelsius(ambientTempRaw);

        System.out.println(
                String.format(" Temp: Object = %fC, Ambient = %fC", objectTempCelsius, ambientTempCelsius));

        lock.lock();
        try {
            cv.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    sensor.disconnect();

}
}
```

I got the following stack error when I run it (image below) :

[image]

I've tried many solution such as this fix:
https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/issues/75

but gave me the same error.

Any tips and tricks appreciated Thanks.

Comment: What does your run configuration contain that you're running it from?

Comment: @DavidConrad do you mean this configuration?: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23729554/39101102-ec5de36c-4662-11e8-968a-c91cde6b7a2a.png

Comment: Yes. It seems you need to provide a VM option -Djava.library.path=/path/to/tinyb/library

Comment: You say you tried the fix in that link but it doesn't look as if you did.

Comment: @DavidConrad while testing I tried this: -Djava.library.path="/home/androidweardev/Desktop/project F/tiny_b/lib/tinyb.jar"

Comment: but this didn't work either in the VM options, gave me the same error as the beginning that why I removed it.

Comment: you can see what I did: image1(VmOption): https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23729554/39101802-0548d8b0-466c-11e8-916f-6d7e1127a577.png , image2(when I run the program again): https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/23729554/39101836-5ec49488-466c-11e8-81ef-41a17a835c4d.png

Comment: It has to point to the directory where the native libraries are. The .so files.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out, for tinyb to work properly it need library files generated from the build. For me it was in /home/user/Desktop/**tinyb-master/src** where those files are in the folder *(libtinyb.so, libtinyb.so.0, libtinyb.so.0.5.0)* and also in :/home/user/Desktop/**tinyb-master/java/jni** where those files are in the folder *(libjavatiny.so, libjavatinyb.so.0, libjavatinyb.so.0.5.0)*.These two path must be added in the VM Option as follow:
 -`Djava.library.path=/home/user/Desktop/tinyb-master/java/jni:/home/user/Desktop/tinyb-master/src` and also don't forget the `tinyb.jar` `(../tinyb-master/java/tinyb.jar)` that need to be added in the java project.

Comment: @DavidConrad Thanks for the help, I just wish there was a more elegant way to add the tinyb library...